# How to valide a multiple nested struct

Tags: go

I am trying to validate this struct, my data is an object with one object property, this one can have multiple objects with its own properties, when I send the data, the govalidator respond with an error.
I am using this library https://github.com/thedevsaddam/govalidator

This is my struct:

```
type Receta struct {
    RecetaID        int    `json:"RecetaId"`
    RecetaNombre    string `json:"RecetaNombre"`
    RecetaCodigo    string `json:"RecetaCodigo"`
    RecetaCategoria string `json:"RecetaCategoria"`
    RecetaSub       string `json:"RecetaSub"`
    ListaReceta     []ListaReceta
}

type Recetas []Receta

type ListaReceta struct {
    IDInsumo         int    `json:"idInsumo"`
    RecetaID         int    `json:"RecetaId"`
    NombreInsumo     string `json:"nombreInsumo"`
    UniddcmpraInsumo string `json:"uniddcmpraInsumo"`
    Tipo             string `json:"tipo"`
    Inicial          string `json:"inicial"`
}
```

This is my function to validate:

```
func (p *Api) CreateReceta(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    rules := govalidator.MapData{
        "RecetaNombre":     []string{"between:0,15"},
        "RecetaCodigo":     []string{"required", "between:0,30"},
        "RecetaCategoria":  []string{"between:0,12"},
        "RecetaSub":        []string{"between:0,12"},
        "idInsumo":         []string{"between:0,12"},
        "nombreInsumo":     []string{"between:0,12"},
        "uniddcmpraInsumo": []string{"between:0,12"},
        "tipo":             []string{"between:0,12"},
        "inicial":          []string{"between:0,12"},
    }

    messages := govalidator.MapData{
        "RecetaNombre":     []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "RecetaCodigo":     []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "RecetaCategoria":  []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "RecetaSub":        []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "idInsumo":         []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "uniddcmpraInsumo": []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "tipo":             []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "inicial":          []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
        "nombreInsumo":     []string{"between:El nombre de este campo debe tener entre 0 a 12"},
    }

    opts := govalidator.Options{
        Request:         r,
        Rules:           rules,
        Messages:        messages,
        RequiredDefault: false,
    }
    v := govalidator.New(opts)
    e := v.Validate()

    if len(e) != 0 {
        errValidate := map[string]interface{}{"validation": e}
        respondwithJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, errValidate)
        return
    }
    receta := models.Receta{}

    r.ParseForm()

    receta.RecetaNombre = r.FormValue("RecetaNombre")
    receta.RecetaCodigo = r.FormValue("RecetaCodigo")
    receta.RecetaCategoria = r.FormValue("RecetaCategoria")
    receta.RecetaSub = r.FormValue("RecetaSub")

    newID, err := p.repo.CreateRecet(r.Context(), &receta)

    fmt.Println(newID)
    if err != nil {
        respondWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Server error")
        return
    }
    id := strconv.Itoa(int(newID))

    respondwithJSON(w, http.StatusCreated, map[string]string{"message": "Successfully created", "ID": id})

}
```

this is how my data is sent:

[image: data from client]

Comment: Which error is returned?

Comment: it didn't give me an error. my problem is when the data is sent , specifically the struct property ListaReceta , cause the data is sent with the [number object][object property ] from client, and my func in the backend don't understand these ones. so i tried to figure out i way to fix it but i couldn't.
So i don't know how to procces multiple nested objects